# What are the step to launch the .Apk file on the Android Market.

Tags: android

I have created android application now I want to launch the .Apk of that application on the Android Market. Can any One please help what are the necessary step that have to follow to launch any application on the android market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the details from these sites. Please have a look here.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113469

Comment: Thanks Andro I have gone through the above link I get exactly that I want.

Comment: Done.. If you like the question then you also up the question -:)

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "launch" you mean "publish". Follow the instructions [listed here](https://market.android.com/publish).